# Groovy trait: cannot find matching method error

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm trying to use Spock and Groovy for testing. I have written simple class/trait for testing as follows:

```
import com.plomber.user.domain.UserDto
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder
@CompileStatic
trait SampleUsers {

    UserDto John = createDto(1, "john@example.com", "simpleJohn1")
    UserDto Bob = createDto(2, "Bob@example.com", "simpleBob1")


    static private UserDto createDto(Integer id, String email, String password) {
        return UserDto.builder()
                .id(id)
                .email(email)
                .password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password))
                .build()
    }
}
```

I'm getting following error when I try to compile it:

```
Error:(10, 20) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method com.plomber.SampleUsers#createDto(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
```

If I assign `John` and `Bob` fields using `UserDto.builder().id(id) ...` instead of `createDto()` method - it works as expected. Do I miss something?

Comment: What version of groovy?

Comment: Have you tried without private and/or static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From groovy docs:

> Traits with static methods cannot be compiled statically or type
>   checked. All static methods/properties/field are accessed dynamically
>   (it’s a limitation from the JVM).

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-traits.html#_static_methods_properties_and_fields