# Cannot find matching method from Groovy to Java

Tags: java, list, groovy, static

```
Groovyc: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method io.swagger.client.util.EmUtil#addLobList(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.
```

I am calling this function in a static block in groovy, as shown below:

```
static {
    Arrays.asList(LOBEnum.values()).forEach {lob -> EmUtil.getInstance().addLobList(lob.name(), lob.getLob())}
    EmUtil.getInstance().setPrefix("CCB_Reference_Data_")
    EmUtil.getInstance().init()
}
```

This calls a java function, as shown below:

```
public void addLobList(String lob, String licenseLob) {
        lobList.add(lob);
        lobLicenseList.add(licenseLob);
    }
```

Comment: Does this relate to your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208997/groovy-trait-cannot-find-matching-method-error

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `lob.name()` and `lob.getLob()` each have a return type of `Object`.  If you want to use the return values of those methods as parameters to your `addLobList` method, the static type checker needs to make sure those are `String` instance.  You can cast those with `(String)`.  Alternatively, you could change the return value of those methods to `String`.

Comment: Hi Jeff, Thank you for the reply.
The return type for lob.name() and lob.getLob() is String only and not object, as shown below:
public final String name() {
        return name;
    }
public String getLob() {
        return lob;
    }